# Is learning Wordpress good for beginning developers?

Tags: wordpress

I've always known wordpress is a really popular cms but have never really got into it yet.

I'll be starting to use wordpress and tampering with grid based systems as another method of coding my sites.

Do you think Wordpress is a good starting point for people learning web development to adapt to different systems and broaden their knowledge base?

Comment: my bad on the title. i ment "is learning wordpress good of beginning developers?"

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking on the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5228180/edit) link in the lower left-hand corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  WordPress would both hide important things you need to learn for web development and make you learn non-portable things like their function APi.  Having said that, I'm a big fan of WordPress, just not as a learning tool.  Each CMS is just too different.

Just like I learned photography using unforgiving black and white, I think it's best learning web development without a CMS, then maybe using one once you've mastered the basics.

If you really want to use some helpers, I would suggest using a framework designed for web development rather than a CMS designed to reduce the need for real web development.  Without more information on the languages and platforms you want to work in, I can't give more specific advice.

Comment: seems like ur both spot on. ive kinda got enough of a grasp on html and css right now to delve into it myself. ill be learning it to build on my existing knowledgebase though, not to migrate to wordpress solely

Comment: are your opinions the same with drupal and joomla out of curiosity? im only interested in wordpress, grids, html/css coding and photoshop for time being

Comment: I don't know Drupal at all, but I know Joomla fairly well (I'm webmaster of http://www.agilenewengland.org which runs on Joomla), and I think it would be a little easier to do real web development with it (vs WordPress).  You can develop modules that you can either place somewhere on the page template, or be driven by a menu option.    I still maintain that if your goal is to learn web development you should start with a web framework (or nothing at all) instead of a CMS.